# Add blogs to "Blogs i Follow" sidebar

Tags: posts, blog, theme-twenty-ten, blogroll

We've been reading through the documentation and watched a video, and gone through all the options in the Dashboard, but whenever we try adding links to the Blog Roll or 'Blogs I follow' section, they never appear on my blog.

How do you add favorite links/links to blogs to the side of the blog?

Comment: Have you checked `LINKS` post type.

Comment: Yep, and it posts a link (as a post), but it doesn't add it to the sidebar. Which is what we're trying to do.

Comment: what you're using ? any plugin or function ? to show those links ?

Comment: Plugins? Functions? Can't you just add a link to the sidebar from within the Dashboard? We're not using any plugins at the moment. Which ones would you suggest?

Comment: We're not hosting our blog ourselves, we're just using Wordpress.com

Comment: Hi Jason, WPSE is aimed at WordPress developers and administrators. Your best bet is to try [WordPress.com support](http://en.support.wordpress.com/contact/)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get what you want.

### Link Manager

Go to `wp-admin/link-manager.php`, add a new link and enable the Links widget in`wp-admin/widgets.php` in one of your sidebars.
However, [the link manager will be removed](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21307) in the next version (WP 3.5). It will be converted to a plugin. I would not rely on it.

### Custom Menu

Create a new custom menu in `wp-admin/nav-menus.php`, name it … *Links* and add custom links to it. Don’t forget to press *Save*. :)

[image]

Now go to `wp-admin/widgets.php`, enable the widget *Custom Menu* and activate the Links menu.

[image]

This will not change any time soon. I asked for it and I was told there are no plans to touch the widgets for 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

The widget method is a decent method, but hand-coding the sidebar is my preferred technique, because it lets you easily change the order, any rel="nofollow/dofollow" settings, titles, etc.

It's pretty simple, all you have to do is make a list using the link's < a > tags within < li > tags, paste the code in the sidebar file, and use the CSS file to style it (if you have a "sidebar" section in the CSS, be sure to put the styling in there so you can find it again).

Since this method doesn't use a widget, it also gives the server a little less to do.